# UI-Router $state.$current wrapper for arbitary state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here is the use case.  Given a stateConfig object, I can access `state.url`, but this only returns the URL specified in that configuration object, not the URL that includes the URL's of a state's parents.  I need to build the full URL to pass into $urlMatcherFactory.compile, to test for matches.

Fortunately, `$state.$current` provides an extended state object, which allows me to iteratively traverse a state's parents and build the full URL for matching. Unforunately, `$state.$current` obviously only wraps the current state, but it would be wonderful if I could wrap an arbitrary state in the same way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expose the internal state implementation by using the `.decorator` hook on `$stateProvider`.  You can decorate any property of the state builder; I chose 'parent' arbitrarily.

---

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) { 
  $stateProvider.decorator('parent', function (internalStateObj, parentFn) {
     // This fn is called by StateBuilder each time a state is registered

     // The first arg is the internal state. Capture it and add an accessor to public state object.
     internalStateObj.self.$$state = function() { return internalStateObj; };

     // pass through to default .parent() function
     return parentFn(internalStateObj); 
  });
});
```

---

Now you can access the internal state object using `.$$state()`, e.gg

```
var publicState = $state.get("foo");
var privateInternalState = publicState.$$state();
```

Comment: Chris you are a baller. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. 
After a bit of logging, i realized that calling `state.$$state()` will return the wrapped state config object.

Comment: `state.$$state()` is a `ui-router-extras` feature.  If you want to access the internal state without `ui-router-extras`, you can register a decorator with the `$stateProvider.decorator()` function and then capture the internal states.  This is how ui-router-extras is able to expose the `state.$$state()` capability.

Comment: Sorry my previous comment was poorly worded. I understand how the decorators work in the docs, but I don't get how to expose them. For instance, with the parent decorator, how do I actually expose it on the state object?