# How to design angularJS resource based authorization routing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, restangular

I'm building a blog system using angularJS, and now trying to build a resource authorization flow that is simple to use for certain resources.
For example, I have the following states `PROPOSALITEM`, `PROPOSALITEM.VIEW` and `PROPOSALITEM.EDIT`. `PROPOSALITEM` is the parent states which resolve proposalItem by the provided `:proposalId` for the child states. `PROPOSALITEM.VIEW` is the view state which allows all users to access it, and `PROPOSALITEM.EDIT` is the edit page which should allow only the `proposal owner` to access.

I found that there's a beautiful structure to do the `role` based authorization flow in angularJS from this article: [Techniques for authentication in AngularJS applications](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec). However what I need now is based on the ownership of the resource to decide if the user could access the route. And I have many resources like `proposal` model which needs to be checked with owner authorization. All these models are provided with a `owner` column. Is there any general solution to deal with this? (I don't want to put the authorization code for each model in its own resolve part because it's difficult to maintain)

```
/* Abstract states. Resolve proposalItem */
.state('PROPOSALITEM', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/proposals/:proposalId',
    template: '<ui-view/>',
    resolve: {
        proposalItem: function($stateParams, ProposalDataService) {
            return ProposalDataService.getItem($stateParams.proposalId);
        }
    }
})
/* View states. Allows all users to access */
.state('PROPOSALITEM.VIEW', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/view',
    template: '...'
})
/* Edit states. Allows only the proposal owner */
.state('PROPOSALITEM.EDIT', {
    url: '/edit',
    template: '...',
    resolve: {
        proposalItem: function($q, proposalItem, UserDataService) {
            var me = UserDataService.getMe();
            // me: {
            //     _id: '1',
            //     name: '...'
            // }
            if (proposalItem.owner._id === me._id) {
                // Authorized.
                return proposalItem;
            } else {
                // Not authorized.
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                deferred.reject(ERROR_KEYS.NOT_AUTHORIZED);
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: This is very good and important question. I actually have a working solution for this,  but need to extract it from my application in a form of module before i can publish it. I plan to have that done by the end of the next week, not sure if you're willing to wait though.

Comment: Even i would be excited to know it. @appmux

Comment: @appmux I'm not in a hurry. Very look forward to your solution!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I normally deal with this case. Create a service which is supposed to deal with the authentication:

```
yourapp.factory('YourResourcePermission', function () {
    return {
        check: function (resource) {
            var me = UserDataService.getMe();
            // return a promise which is resolved with the data
            // if the user has permission, or rejected otherwise.
        }
    };
});
```

Then you use this service as the resolve param for the status you need:

```
.state('PROPOSALITEM.EDIT', {
url: '/edit',
template: '...',
resolve: function (proposalItem, YourResourcePermission) {  
    return YourResourcePermission.check(proposalItem);
}
```

})

In this way you can keep all your permission logic away from the routes in a dedicated (and reusable) service.

If you have a few states requiring the same require boilerplate, you can use Angular $provide.decorator to automatically inject your custom logic to your states. 
See this: https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras/blob/master/src/dsr.js#L10 and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/26848546/3794660 as references on how you can decorate the $stateProvider and create your custom state type that basically has the 'resolve' param already set.

Hope this is helpful.